# Multiple Users Types Register

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building an application that will allow access to various types of users, they are, students, parents, teachers and Administration. So far I have a model for User, which has fields, Email and Password, which serve as credentials to log into the site, and a Model for each type of users (Model Student, Model Professor, etc)

How do I register a user in only one page? Something like that.

---

Name:
address:         <---- Student Model
....

Email :
Pass:             <----- User Model
Pass Confirm:

Save Button

---

I already have a page to create a user, through my User Model 
(I can register and the do login and logout, and validate all data for this 'table'.) 
I want to have the data of both model (User and UserType - Student/Parents/Admin/etc) 
in the same page and then save all data to their respective models.

I've been searching and I realized that using 'devise' would be a viable solution, but do not quite understand how this works.

Someone explain to me the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Associations**

You'll need to look at your [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html):

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :student
  delegate :address, to: :student, prefix: true
end

#app/models/student.rb
Class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This alone will allow you to call the following:

```
@user = User.find params[:id] #-> example
@user.student
@user.student_address #-> if using delegate
```

--

**Build**

To populate both models upon save, we use the `build` functionality inside Rails to create a blank version of the dependent model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   ...
   before_create :build_student
end
```

This will build the `student` object (equivalent of `@user.student.build`) before saving both objects to your DB. This will allow you to populate the `Student` model at a later time